# Variadic template with template and non-type parameters

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Having the code snippet below (under C++17 standard):

```
template <class ...TParams>
class Wrapper {
public:
    template <template <class, TParams...> class TTemplate, class TValue, TParams ...params>
    class Base {
    public:
        TTemplate<TValue, params...> value;
    };
};
template <class T, bool Param1, int Param2>
class Class {
public:
    T value;
    bool boolean = Param1;
    int integer = Param2;
};
template <class T, bool Param1, int Param2>
class Derived :public Wrapper<bool, int>::Base<Class, T, Param1, Param2> {};
int main() {
    Derived<int,true,0> test;
    return 0;
}
```

**MSVC** fails to compile, saying "**the template parameter list for class template 'Class' does not match the template parameter list for template parameter 'TTemplate'**"
May anyone explain the reason why Class doesn't match TTemplate? Thanks in advance.

Comment: clang 12.0.0 has no problem with this code

Comment: @drompix gcc, up to and including trunk rejects the code. But with a different error.

Comment: @cigien MSVC and c++17, updated in problem description

Comment: @true_mogician take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656291/errors-while-using-templates-templates-parameters

Comment: @drompix Kind of different, this questioner want a type template in template, but I'm trying for a template with variadic non-type parameters in template